# Single displacement reaction

Tags: redox

Will sodium metal, if mixed well with iron oxide, displace the iron in a chemical reaction? I know thermite involves the mixture of aluminium powder and iron oxide, and the single displacement reaction results in molten iron and aluminium trichloride. The other day I melted some sodium metal to the point of melting but reacting with the air. I wonder if either mashing up sodium with iron oxide and then igniting, or adding melted sodium to iron oxide will act like a thermite reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Sodium metal will react with iron (III) oxide to produce sodium oxide and iron.

$\ce{6Na +Fe2O3 -> 3Na2O + 2Fe}$

This is also like a thermite reaction, so try to use the soam\e method as the reaction.